# Understanding why "self" takes significant percentage in Android profile trace

Tags: android, performance, ddms

I have the following method that runs on Android devices:

```
public int push(int newElement) {
    assert !myIsIterating : "concurrent modification";
    ensureCapacity(mySize + 1);
    myArray[mySize] = newElement;
    return mySize++;
}
```

I have run this code under the android profiler (the one that is installed with ADT tools in Eclipse), here are the results:

[image]

The "self" part of this method takes roughly 70% of the time spent in this method, even though the code in it seems to be fairly simple.

How can this be? what may be taking most of the time in this method? (for example - is assert checked at runtime?)